# How to iterate more than 10 directories using "for dir in equil[0123]"?

Tags: linux, bash, for

`for dir in equil[0123]` could iterate over folders of `equil0`, `equil1`,`equil2` and `equil3`. But if I have folders with name number more than 10, e.g. `equil23`, how to properly refer to them? How the separator is recognised in `equil[0123]`?

Comment: Running the `for` loop as you describe only outputs one string `equil[0123]`.  Something like `for dir in equil{0..3}; do echo $dir; done` would use bash brace expansion and output four lines with `equil0`, `equil1`, `equil2`, `equil3`.  For more than 10, set the number to higher than 10: `for dir in equil{0..100}; do echo $dir; done`.  Please clarify your question if none of that helps.

Comment: You could also use `extglob` to iterate over directories matching `equil` followed by one or more digits with the pattern `equil+([[:digit:]])`